# Is :not(.disabled) always necessary for on eventhandlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

Is there a way to get rid of `:not(.disabled)` in the eventhandler, for `li` that have `.disabled`, so "Do stuff" still happens?

I'm asking because I remember as I didn't had to add the `:not(.disabled)` to a button element or maybe it was a button acting like dropdown with `li a` elements inside.

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="fooId" class="disabled">
        text
    </li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('body').on('click', '#fooId:not(.disabled)', function () {
    // "Do stuff.."
});
```

**UPDATE**:

[Boostrap dropdown li a disabled](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-disabled)

Disabled menu items
Add .disabled to a `<li>` in the dropdown to disable the link.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
  <li><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I used this kind before, where `a` was included.

I was refactoring the code to another class and while I was at it, I removed `a` element too, and now I had to add `:not(.disabled)` to the eventhandler to not get in there for elements that are disabled as expected. **But to my surprise**, I guess it doesn't work if you remove the `a` element. (I have to test it again).

Comment: So you want "Do stuff" to execute even though `<li>` has disabled class?

Comment: No, not if it's disabled.

Comment: I guess `.disabled` gets added dynamically? If so, then you definitely need that on the event handler otherwise it will execute

Comment: You can put the condition `if (!$(this).is(':disabled'))` to verify if the element is disabled or not before executing further code.

Comment: @radbyx, `li` elements do not have property `disabled`..You can make them appear disabled using some css as you are doing using `.disabled`. For `input` disabled elements, events are not triggered..

Comment: Yes, I add .disabled dynamically, if the rows in the table below is selected.

Comment: @RayonDabre Ah, that's just might be my missing link. I had lead my self to believe that all element has/use `.disabled`, in a sweet maner as I once experience with some bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is:

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function () {
  if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
    return;  // Do stuff won't execute for disabled li, but will work for others
  // "Do stuff.."
});
```

Comment: This will also work yes, but I'm trying to find a solution without using javascript. Like here in bootstrap: I will update with an example:

Disabled menu items
Add .disabled to a <li> in the dropdown to disable the link.

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
  <li><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: @radbyx if you want to avoid javascript, only way to do this would be to use   css [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property like `li.disabled{pointer-events:none`} but then there is an issue of browser support :/

Comment: Yeah okay, I would prefer Js then. But point was, I would prefer doing nothing, and let the "magic" happend instead of writing extra JS. You can see my Update, where Bootstrap has a dropdown where the li is disabled. In that example I don't have to do extra JS. The event isn't even fired, which are Great! :) But after I removed the `a` it doesn't work. And it most be the reason I think atm.

Comment: @radbyx actually there is no magic. *"The event isn't even fired"* what event..? Did something happen when you clicked the active items? No. nothing happens because none of them have any events. Bootstrap just "styled" one item to look like it's not clickable, but it's still clickable. Try binding an event listener to it.

Comment: @radbyx just paste this code in that bootstrap page `$('li.disabled').click(function(){alert('fail')});` and it shows alert, which means events do fire.

Comment: Yeah I can see. Same as for the bootstrap example. So it's just for styling as you said, and can be used with the right css selector. I just had like 10-20 examples for months where the disabled function worked for me. And I never had to add ":not(.disabled" before. I might rememer wrong, but it's weird. Maybe I remember some day. Oh well, it's no problem to add the extra lines if it's really nesessary. I was just convinced it wasn't nesessary, hence it feels wrong. Trying to be lazy in the right way :)

Comment: Try this. Only enable will fire an alert. It might have some bootstrap.js But it's shows how .disabled can do it..

                <button id="testbtnEnabled" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                    enabled
                </button>
                <button id="testbtnDisabled" class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="button">
                    disabled
                </button>
        $('#testbtnEnabled').on('click', function() {
            alert('enabled');
        });
        $('#testbtnDisabled').on('click', function() {
            alert('disabled');
        });

Comment: Not if you have Bootstrap v3.3.5 Js in your bundle.

Comment: @radbyx [here you go, still works](https://jsfiddle.net/4j1pja5w/1/). I think you need to realize that I have explained how things work and gave you multiple demos... wake up! -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `:not(.disabled')` as long as `id=fooId` is unique through out the DOM structure. You can use below code -

```
$('body').on('click', '#fooId', function () {
    // "Do stuff.."
});
```

Or If there are multiple `li` elements with `class="disabled"` then you can use below code

```
 $('body').on('click', 'li.disabled', function () {
        // "Do stuff.."
    });
```

Comment: I think your last example would do the opposite of what I'm trying. I should make a fiddle for this I guess. I thought I could explain it clear enough, i'm sorry.

Comment: I have put second solution by seeing at your sentence " for li that have .disabled, so "Do stuff" still happens?" , I thought you want to do your stuff with li having class disabled.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have made an Update, which should make it clear. I guess I have to add the `a` to the DOM and the eventhandler again I guess.